# Can't name my C++ static functions with similar names

Tags: c++, object, methods

I have a C++ class where I declare two static methods that have (and they should have) similar names, but definitely not the **same** name. So I did this:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Cat;

class Cat {
public:
    int age;
    Cat * mother;
    Cat * father;

    Cat(){};
    ~Cat(){};

    static Cat* walk_to_min(Cat* c);
    static Cat* walk_to(Cat* c, int distance);
};
```

But when I try to compile, G++ gives me this:

```
cats.cpp:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘walk_to’
cats.cpp:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘walk_to’
```

But if I change - for example - `walk_to` to `gogo` it works. So I guess it has something to do with the naming of these methods.

What's going on? Why the methods can't be named like I want them to. Imagine a BST, where you have BST_delete and BST_delete_min, sometimes you want to have methods with similar names. What can I do?

**Update**. Sorry everyone, I wasn't showing the real code. this is the real code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class BST {
public:
    int key;
    BST* leftChild;
    BST* rightChild;

    BST();
    BST(int t) : key(t) {}
    ~BST(){};

    void inOrder(BST* bstree);
    void preOrder(BST* bstree);
    void postOrder(BST* bstree);

    static BST* delete_min(BST* root);
    static BST* delete(BST* root, int value);
    static BST* search(BST* element, int value);
};
```

by the way, both my methods delete_in and delete have their definitions empty:

```
BST* BST::delete_min(BST* root)
{
}

BST* BST::delete(BST* root, int value)
{
}
```

and the error:

```
L2Q1-dunder-mifflin-cpp.cpp:21: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’
L2Q1-dunder-mifflin-cpp.cpp:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘delete’
```

Thanks

Comment: Can I know why the heck you have a struct Cat; just before class Cat?!

Comment: please post `walk_to_min/walk_to` function definitions

Comment: Aside: you probably shouldn't have pointers in C++.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted is only 16 lines long, but the error message is for line 22. So your problem may be something outside of these lines. Please post the entire program (or at least a more complete subset).

Comment: @KristopherJohnson Well, not the entire program. A reduced code sample that serves only to manifest the compiler error and points out where it occurs in a comment is preferable.

Comment: @Borgleader I have the struct to I can have a property in my class that refers to another Cat object

Comment: @Borgleader That will generate a warning but will pass the compilation . At least on VC2010.

Comment: @rodrigoalves Then take it away it's useless. [See here](https://ideone.com/UoKsox)

Comment: @rodrigoalves The error message is about line 22, as Kristopher said. You need to investigate this. Look carefully at the syntax before `walk_to` in that line. You must have a typo, or some form of bad syntax there. Voting to put on hold -- as it stands, it's not clear how anyone can help you.

Comment: Hi everyone, I wasn't showing the real code.But there it is now, hope you're still willing to help!

Comment: Please vote this question up whenever you see the update.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`delete`** is a reserved C++ keyword, you can't use it for a function name - you can't name a function something like 'int' or 'float' either, for the same reasons. The **`static BST`** is the "unexpected" part before the keyword `delete` that the compiler was complaining about.

You could name the function something like `destroy`, `free`, `remove`, `deallocate`, `delete_all`, `delete_entire`, `delete_tree`, etc... Whatever makes the most sense given the purpose of the function.